# Dúvida sobre pergunta pendente

Tags: debate

Bem, estou iniciando no `PT-SO` portanto a pergunta é a caráter informativo.

Hoje me deparei, com uma **[Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171560/61561)** que foi colocada como **PENDENTE**, com a seguinte informação:

> marcada como pendente como fora de escopo por jbueno, Bacco, bigown? 6
>   horas atrás
>
> Esta pergunta parece não pertencer ao site. Segundo os usuários, este
>   foi o motivo
>
> "Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.
>   Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a
>   outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a
>   criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável." – jbueno,
>   Bacco, bigown Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta
>   para que fique adequada.

Então dentro disso gostaria de mais informações dos usuários mais experientes, sobre o que é estar fora do escopo? Sendo que no meu modo de ver a pergunta é claramente sobre `Programação` .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Renan, antes de mais nada, é uma excelente iniciativa vir no meta questionar as razões quando se está aprendendo a utilizar o site e em como a comunidade funciona.

Além disso, note que suspensão ou fechamento de perguntas não é algo de caráter pessoal. O ponto é sempre com relação ao conteúdo.

Quanto ao status "pendente como fora de escopo", note que esta é uma mensagem padrão que inclui várias causas, as quais são especificadas na linha seguida como o motivo da suspensão.

Neste caso, a mensagem é clara:

> "Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação..."

Eu sei que é meio confuso isto ser fora de escopo, mas considere que o objetivo do site é ajudar não somente o autor da pergunta, mas todos os possíveis visitantes.

Portanto, uma questão que não apresente um problema válido não será útil para ninguém. Se o próprio autor da pergunta disse que o código está certo e ele cometeu um engano qualquer, o problema nunca poderá ser reproduzido e a pergunta perde a razão de existir.

O caso de um erro de digitação é similar. Vamos supor que haja uma pergunta  sobre um cálculo em uma linguagem dinâmica que retornou o valor incorreto, mas no fim das contas alguém nota que o usuário apenas se esqueceu de uma letra no nome de alguma função. Isto é geralmente considerado fora de escopo simplesmente porque não agrega em nada. Na grande maioria dos casos invalida completamente o que foi perguntado.

Uma analogia: é como quando alguém pensa que o computador queimou, mas só esqueceu de colocar ele na tomada. :P

Para uma pergunta fazer parte do escopo, não basta apenas ter como tema *programação*, ela deve ser uma pergunta válida sobre programação.